# Finding the modified factorial N modulo some number coprime to N

Tags: algorithm, math, factorial, modular-arithmetic

Given two numbers `N` and `p`, let `k` be the maximum power of `p` such that `p^k` divides `N!` and let `d = N!/(p^k)`. So `d` and `p` are coprimes.

How do I find **`d mod p`**? Direct iterations will be impractical as `N!` will be very high when `N` is high. A more efficient algorithm is required to find the expression.

Comment: May I ask is `p` prime?

Comment: I don't think there can be an efficient general algorithm for this. Consider the case `p > N` - then you can't do better than those `N` multiplications to find `d ( = N!) mod p`.

Comment: Also how big is `p` are there any limitations?

Comment: @us2012 however even if you have to do all the multiplications if p is a prime number you can store only the remainder modulo `p` and avoid the hyper big numbers that follow from factorials.

Comment: @Boris Yeah, of course, but that applies to any `p`.

Comment: @us2012 For my note - yes. However, I have one more reason to ask about whether `p` is prime: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson's_theorem

Comment: p is not prime but you can have it <10^7.

Answer (score 1):

Here is O(N) algorithm:

```
int d=1;
for(int i=1;i<=N;++i)
{
    d*=i;
    while(d%p==0)
      d/=p;
    d=d%p;
}
```

It doesn't require storing huge numbers, so may be acceptable. I suspect that O(p) algorithm is possible (because numbers will repeat after every k*p), but the code will be a bit more complex.